# List of Type Class Posting null in the Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have data coming in Model and i want to get the data on form Post all model is posted fine except the List of class type in Model is posted null.

I know i am doing something wrong in view at rendering but unable to resolve it.

Here is the chunk from view where i am rendering:

```
@model InovaClassic.Models.RegisterModel
 <table>

                @if (Model.PostReq != null && Model.PostReq._questions != null && Model.PostReq._questions.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.PostReq._questions.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                    <legend style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray; font-size: 16px;">Questions</legend>
                        }
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label(Model.PostReq._questions[i].Title)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PostReq._questions[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PostReq._questions[i].QuestionnaireId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="Answer[@i]" class="required" style="width:520px;height:20px;"></textarea>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    }
                }
            </table>
```

Here is my Register Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, FormCollection Form)
    {
        model.PostReq = new PostRequirements();
        ViewBag.Token = "";

        if (!model.Availability.EndsAfter)
            model.Availability.EndsAfterValue = 1;

        //model.Resume.UploadedAt = DateTime.Now;
        //model.Resume.ApplicationId = 0;
        //model.Resume.IsDefault = true;



        foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                //DoSomethingWith(error);
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                int PostId;
                int? ApplicationId = null;
                string confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName.Trim(), model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, true);
                var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new string[] { model.UserName.Trim() }, new string[] { "applicant" });
                Applicant App = new Applicant();
                App = Applicant.MapApplicant(model.RegisterVm);
                App.UserId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == model.UserName.Trim()).UserId;
                db.Applicant.Add(App);

                db.SaveChanges();

                bool IsNumber = int.TryParse(Form["PostId"],out PostId);

                if (IsNumber)
                { 

                    ApplicationId = ApplyJob(App.UserId, PostId);


                    /*if (model.PostReq != null && model.PostReq._questions != null)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < model.PostReq._questions.Count; i++)
                        {
                            QuestionnaireAnswers answer = new QuestionnaireAnswers();

                            answer.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                            answer.QuestionId = model.PostReq._questions[i].QuestionnaireId;
                            answer.Answer = Form["Answer[" + i + "]"].ToString();

                            db.QuestionnaireAnswers.Add(answer);

                        }
                    }*/
                    if (Form["QuestionsCount"] != null)
                    {

                        int Count = Convert.ToInt32(Form["QuestionsCount"]);

                        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                        {
                            QuestionnaireAnswers answer = new QuestionnaireAnswers();

                            answer.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                            answer.QuestionId = Convert.ToInt32(Form["QuestionSeqId[" + i + "]"]);
                            answer.Answer = Form["Answer[" + i + "]"].ToString();

                            db.QuestionnaireAnswers.Add(answer);

                        }

                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string File = SaveDocument(ApplicationId, i);
                        int TitleIndex = i - 1;
                        ApplicationDocument applicationDocument = new ApplicationDocument();
                        applicationDocument.ApplicationId = Convert.ToInt32(ApplicationId);
                        applicationDocument.DocumentTitle = Form["PostReq._documents[" + TitleIndex + "]"];
                        applicationDocument.Path = File;


                        db.ApplicationDocuments.Add(applicationDocument);

                    }
                }
                //if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Form["PostId"].ToString()))
                //{


                    string FileName = SaveResume(App.UserId, Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase);

                    if (FileName != "")
                    {
                        model.Resume.Path = FileName;
                        model.Resume.UserId = App.UserId;
                        model.Resume.UploadedAt = DateTime.Now;
                        model.Resume.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                        db.Resumes.Add(model.Resume);
                    }

                    if (Form["ends"] == "1")
                    {
                        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = true;
                        model.Availability.EndsBy = false;
                        model.Availability.EndsAfter = false;

                    }
                    if (Form["ends"] == "2")
                    {
                        model.Availability.EndsAfter = true;
                        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = false;
                        model.Availability.EndsBy = false;

                    }
                    if (Form["ends"] == "3")
                    {
                        model.Availability.EndsBy = true;
                        model.Availability.EndsAfter = false;
                        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = false;
                    }
                    model.Availability.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                    model.Availability.UserId = App.UserId;

                    db.Availabilities.Add(model.Availability);

               // }

                //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Form["PostId"].ToString()))
                //{



                //    string FileName = SaveResume(App.UserId, Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase);

                //    if (FileName != "")
                //    {
                //        model.Resume.Path = FileName;
                //        model.Resume.UserId = App.UserId;
                //        model.Resume.UploadedAt = DateTime.Now;
                //        model.Resume.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                //        db.Resumes.Add(model.Resume);
                //    }

                //    if (Form["ends"] == "1")
                //    {
                //        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = true;
                //        model.Availability.EndsBy = false;
                //        model.Availability.EndsAfter = false;

                //    }
                //    if (Form["ends"] == "2")
                //    {
                //        model.Availability.EndsAfter = true;
                //        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = false;
                //        model.Availability.EndsBy = false;

                //    }
                //    if (Form["ends"] == "3")
                //    {
                //        model.Availability.EndsBy = true;
                //        model.Availability.EndsAfter = false;
                //        model.Availability.DoesNotEnd = false;
                //    }
                //    model.Availability.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                //    model.Availability.UserId = App.UserId;

                //    db.Availabilities.Add(model.Availability);

                //    for (int i = 0; i < model.PostReq._questions.Count; i++)
                //    {
                //        QuestionnaireAnswers answer = new QuestionnaireAnswers();

                //        answer.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                //        answer.QuestionId = model.PostReq._questions[i].QuestionnaireId;
                //        answer.Answer = Form["Answer[" + i + "]"].ToString();

                //        db.QuestionnaireAnswers.Add(answer);

                //    }


                //    for (int i = 1; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                //    {
                //        string File = SaveDocument(ApplicationId, i);

                //        ApplicationDocument applicationDocument = new ApplicationDocument();
                //        applicationDocument.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
                //        applicationDocument.DocumentTitle = Form["PostReq._documents[" + i + "]"];
                //        applicationDocument.Path = File;


                //        db.ApplicationDocuments.Add(applicationDocument);

                //    }


                //    //db.SaveChanges();
                //}
                //Applicant MyApplicant = Applicant.MapApplicant(model.RegisterVm);

                //Test Code
                //Resume resume = new Resume();
                //resume.Title = "CV97";
                //resume.IsDefault = true;
                //resume.Path = "37_AdLoader[1].htm";
                //resume.UserId = App.UserId;
                //resume.ApplicationId = null;
                //db.Resumes.Add(resume);

                db.SaveChanges();
                //WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                string ReturnURL = TempData["ReturnUrl"] == null ? "" : TempData["ReturnUrl"].ToString();
                string str_rev = ReturnURL.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToString();
                CoverLetter Letter = MyHelpers.RegisterLetter();
                UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
                //string url = MyHelpers.GetBaseUrl() + u.Action("ConfirmAccount", "Account", new { id = confirmationToken, user = model.UserName.Trim(), ReturnUrl = ReturnURL });
                string url = MyHelpers.GetBaseUrl() + u.Action("ConfirmAccount", "Account", new { id = confirmationToken, user = model.UserName.Trim() });
                string link = "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">Confirmation Link</a>";
                string Body = Letter.Body.Replace("%link%", link);
                MyHelpers.SendMail(model.Email, Letter.Subject, Body);
                ViewBag.Token = "1";

                return RedirectToAction("Result", "Post", new { id = 3 });
                //return View();
                // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }


        List<Country> Countries = db.Country.ToList();
        SelectList CountryList = new SelectList(Countries, "Id", "Name", model.RegisterVm.Country);

        List<Country> VisaCountries = db.Country.ToList();
        SelectList VisaCountryList = new SelectList(VisaCountries, "Id", "Name", model.RegisterVm.VisaCountry);

        List<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses = db.MaritalStatus.ToList();
        SelectList MaritalStatusList = new SelectList(MaritalStatuses, "Id", "Name", model.RegisterVm.MaritalStatus);

        List<Title> Titles = db.Title.ToList();
        SelectList TitleList = new SelectList(Titles, "Id", "Name", model.RegisterVm.Title);

        List<VisaType> VisaTypes = db.VisaType.ToList();
        SelectList VisaTypeList = new SelectList(VisaTypes, "Id", "Name", model.RegisterVm.VisaType);

        ViewBag.CountryList = CountryList;
        ViewBag.VisaCountryList = VisaCountryList;
        ViewBag.MaritalStatusList = MaritalStatusList;
        ViewBag.TitleList = TitleList;
        ViewBag.VisaTypeList = VisaTypeList;


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        //return View(model);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Account/RegisterUser.cshtml", model);
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public RegisterViewModel RegisterVm { get; set; }

        public Resume Resume { get; set; }

        public Availability Availability { get; set; }

        public PostRequirements PostReq { get; set; }



    }
```

See PostRequirements:

```
public class PostRequirements
    {
        public List<Question> _questions { get; set; }
        public List<string> _documents { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show action signature

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Form` tags.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 { }
```

This should be wrapped around your form elements.

Comment: it is wrapped my all model properties posting except the list which i am iterating

Comment: You should include that as well.

Comment: can you tell me why list Model.PostReq._question post null in action

Comment: when u debug, u dont see the values in `FormCollection` ?

Comment: in form collection they come but on model the questions is null

Comment: ok you need a model binder then. You wont get it in your Model. You can either have a custom model binder or iterate form collection.

Comment: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/11/07/null-collectionsarrays-from-mvc-model-binding/